# Trying to locate theme generator for vscode

Tags: templates, visual-studio-code, themes, generator

I'm trying to locate a theme editor/generator that I used about 2 years ago. It may have been a project template instead of extension I can't remember. It had a simple UI option where you could select a few colors by hex or eye dropper and it would fill in the rest with variations. It also had a intermediate UI page which had categorized and structured sections to easily choose from and again enter hex or use eyedropper.

For the life of me I cannot remember the name and have been unable to locate it. If anyone knows the name or where to find it I would appreciate it.

Comment: https://coder-coder.com/vs-code-theme-color-generator/ ?

Comment: Interface is similar but it wasn't online, you could build/generate the theme local to upload later.

Comment: Note: https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/02/29/lets-play-the-guessing-game/